# in bash how can I "break" a watch then re-add it?

Tags: bash

I'm using watch because I need to detect new files created in a log folder and tail them. I can't seem to use tail ie. tail /dir/*.log and have it detect new files created in the folder. So at the moment I'm using

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
   watch -n 1 "tail /tmp/tomcat-logs/*.log | grep --line-buffered \"ERROR\|INFO: Server startup in:\|Exception:\" | sed 's/ERROR/PROBLEMO/g' | tee /tmp/errchecker-log.txt"
   echo "do some processing here when a token is found"
done
```

In this case, when a token is found "ERROR" I need to stop watching - then grep the output ( count lines etc.. ) then re-watch until the next error .. rinse repeat

Cheers

Comment: You'd be better off using Python for this. There is even `pyinotify` to efficiently watch for filesystem changes so you don't need to poll.

Comment: A less resource intensive way of doing this may be to set up a cron job that runs once every minute and greps for the ERROR message and performs the associated action. That would avoid the issues of shell script with loop hanging.

Comment: @JohnZwinck right you are - was definitely easier

Answer (score 0):

Use `while read`

```
#!/bin/bash

while read LINE; do
    echo $LINE
done < <(for i in $(seq 10); do echo $i; sleep 1; done)
```